# How to declare a variable inside a Scheme function?

Tags: scheme

Is it possible to do so? Let's say I want to get the last element of a list, I would create a variable `i = 0`, and increment it until it equals to length. Any idea? An example would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What algorithm did you have in mind for getting the last element?

Comment: @larsmans: traverse through the list until `i` equals to length? Does it sound reasonable in Scheme?

Comment: it sounds like a waste because you're traversing the list twice; the first time to compute the length. The algorithm would be linear-time (not quadratic as @sepp2k assumes), but two-pass and not idiomatic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways to declare a variable; the cleanest one is `let`:

```
(let ((x some-expr))
  ; code block that uses x
```

But you don't need this to get the last element of a list. Just use recursion:

```
(define (last xs)
  (if (null? (cdr xs))
    (car xs)
    (last (cdr xs))))
```

Note: if you want, you can use a variable to cache `cdr`'s result:

```
(define (last xs)
  (let ((tail (cdr xs)))
    (if (null? tail)
      (car xs)
      (last tail))))
```

Comment: Many thanks, very nice solutions! By the way, I'm a little confused about the if statement above. Does the `last tail` belong to the `if` or it is a separate statement? How can we differentiate?

Comment: @Chan: `(last tail)` is the else-part of the `if` expression. You can tell by the parens and by my use of indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to define local variables in scheme, either using `let` or `define` inside a function. Using `set!`, it's also possible to reassign a variable like you imagine.

That being said, you should probably not solve your problem this way. In Scheme it's generally good practice to avoid `set!` when you don't need to (and in this case you definitely don't need to). Further iterating over a list using indices is usually a bad idea as scheme's lists are linked lists and as such random access O(n) (making the `last` function as you want to implement it `O(n^2)`).

So a simple recursive implementation without indices would be more idiomatic and faster than what you're planning to do and as such preferable.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is to remove the last element from the list. I could reverse the list, then remove the first element, but it seemed too inefficient. Thinking in Scheme is completely odd comparing with other traditional language like C or C++.

Comment: Is there any other way to redefine a variable in Scheme, besides using `set!`?